# Inserting at the top Row of a large TStringGrid

Tags: delphi

I fear this might be a "how long is a piece of string" question, but wondered if anyone has some hard figures or advice.

I have a TStringGrid which might have 3,600 rows, maybe more, we are not sure yet.  Since the monitor obviously doesn't have room for this, only 20 or 30 rows are shown on screen. Unfortunately, those are the first ones written and the user has to scroll down to see the rows as they are added.

It might be more user-friendly to reverse the order of the rows,m with newest first and oldest last. To do that, I would need to do something like this (code may not be exact)

```
  // slightly quicker if there are many rows & no flicker
  myStringGrid.Visible := False;      
  rowCount := myStringGrid.RowCount;
  for row := 1 to Pred(rowCount) do
      myStringGrid.Rows[row + 1] := myStringGrid.Rows[row];
  myStringGrid.RowCount := myStringGrid.RowCount + 1;
  // now add new row...
  myStringGrid.Cells[1, 0] := <somthing>;
  myStringGrid.Cells[1, 1] := <somthing else>;
  myStringGrid.Cells[1, 2] := <etc>;
  TestRunDataStringGrid.Visible := True;
```

I am concerned about performance. If no one has any experience, I will code a test & report back.

Just wondered if anyone had experience or an opinion of doing this...

Comment: Maybe you could use a "virtual" control instead? Say a VirtualTreeView  (http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=blogsection&id=2&Itemid=33/) or a TListView in virtual mode?

Comment: probably don't even need virtual mode for this many rows

Comment: +1 to both. What a pity I don't understand what a virtual control is :-/  but Uwe doesn't seem to think I will have problems with TStringGrid with 3.6k ROws (and about 6 columns)

Comment: Delphi's string grid is an built-in control, it's not an wrapper around something provided by Windows: shifting a few thousands rows shouldn't be a problem because there's no messaging overhead (as would be the case with most Windows-provided controls).

Comment: I had about 160.000 rows and more than 20 columns in a String grid some time ago(for testing purpose) and it managed without any issue... but it all comes down to the client's system spec.

Comment: @Cosmin I doubt that shifting 3.6k rows in a non-virtual TListView would be noticeable. Internally the data structure will be very similar to Delphi TList I suspect.

Comment: @Davin: internally yes, it becomes problematic if you need to `SendMessage` every single change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    ---
    ---
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  type
  TStringGridHack = class(TStringGrid)
  protected
    procedure InsertRow(ARow: Longint);
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


procedure TStringGridHack.InsertRow(ARow: Longint);
var
  iRow: Integer;
begin
  iRow := Row;
  while ARow < FixedRows do Inc(ARow);
  RowCount := RowCount + 1;
  MoveRow(RowCount - 1, ARow);
  Row := iRow;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TStringGridHack(StringGrid1).InsertRow(1);
end;
```

Comment: +1  It doesn't really comment on the limits of TSringGrid, but it does improve on my hasitilly cobbled together code. I presume that MoveRow() might be marginally quicker than doing it explicitly. Thanks.

Comment: depending on the version of Delphi your running you could also create a "class helper" so that you don't have to hardcast each time you need to insert a new row, furthermore if you define the class helper in a "utilities" unti, you can take advantage of the "hacked" string grid in all forms, frames etc. i.e. type TStringGridHelper = class Helper for TStringGrid and copy the above code in the class body, have fun :-)

Comment: @Dorin: Or just use the simple and reliable thing from the past - a global procedure: `procedure InsertRowIntoStringGrid(AGrid: TStringGrid; ARow: Longint);`. :-P

Comment: +1 @Ulrich class helper should be last resort, subclassing is reasonable but I certainly wouldn't name it "Hack", an unbound procedure is also a most excellent solution!

Comment: @Ulrich: As per the above answer, we cant use MoveRow in the global procedure as it is protected method

Comment: @Bharat OK, but you could easily get access to it through the well-known protected hack

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a virtual grid control instead of VirtualTreeView. I have one, written by Roman Mochalov (Роман Мочалов), which I believe to be 100% open source, but not much available on the web.  I have a [link](http://cid-f5bb35ae00415bc7.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/ExGridView.zip) here [on skydrive]: